# Python: Server Creator - Not writing to file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pickle

new to python, just trying to create a simple minecraft server properties file creator within a GUI, I have found that it does not correctly write to file and gives me this error - "

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python33\Projects\Server\GUI.py", line 26, in top
    f.write(line1)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

"

Any help would be greatly welcomed!

```
import pickle, shelve, sys, os
from tkinter import *
f = open('server.properties', 'w')
def start():
    os.system("start.bat")
def top():
    val1 = players.get()
    val1 = str(val1)
    line1 = ("max-player="+val1+"\n")
    line1 = str(line1)
    var2 = pvp.get()
    var2 = str(var2)
    line2 = ("pvp="+var2+"\n")
    var3 = motd.get()
    var3 = str(var3)
    line3 = ("motd="+var3+"\n")
    var4 = monsters.get()
    var4 = str(var4)
    line4 = ("spawn-monsters="+var4+"\n")
    var5 = gamemode.get()
    var5 = str(var5)
    line5 = ("gamemode="+var5+"\n")
    var6 = internalip.get()
    var6 = str(var6)
    line6 = ("server-ip="+var6+"\n")
    f.write(line1)
    f.write(line2)
    f.write(line3)
    f.write(line4)
    f.write(line5)
    f.write(line6)
    f.close()

gui = Tk()
gui.minsize(width=500, height=500)
gui.maxsize(width=500, height=500)
players = StringVar()
pvp = StringVar()
motd = StringVar()
monsters = StringVar()
gamemode = StringVar()
internalip = StringVar()

gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.title("Server Creator")


lbl1 = Label(text="Please enter Y or N for each value given.").pack()
btn1 = Button(text="OK", command=top).pack()
lbl2 = Label(text="Enter the player limit below.").pack()
ent1 = Entry(gui,textvariable=players).pack()
lbl3 = Label(text="Enter true or false to enable PVP.").pack()
ent2 = Entry(gui,textvariable=pvp).pack()
lbl4 = Label(text="Enter the message of the day.").pack()
ent3 = Entry(gui,textvariable=motd).pack()
lbl5 = Label(text="Enter true or false for spawning monsters.").pack()
ent4 = Entry(gui,textvariable=monsters).pack()
lbl6 = Label(text="Enter 2 for adventure, 1 for creaive or 0 for survival").pack()
ent5 = Entry(gui,textvariable=gamemode).pack()
lbl7 = Label(text="Enter the internal server IP.").pack()
ent6 = Entry(gui,textvariable=internalip).pack()

lblfinal = Label(text="Click the Start button below to being the server,\n make sure you have clicked the OK button above to save your settings.").pack()
btnstart = Button(text="Start", command=start).pack()


gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: It just means that you're trying to do an input/output operation on a closed file.In order to get ride of this error,you need to open a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error it means you're trying to play with a closed file which doesn't make sense.
 so make sure that the file is open before doing anything...

This probably means that one of your lines of code is closing the file before your ultimate `f.write()` execution. The best suggestion i can give is to call `f = open('file','w')` just before `f.write()`

Comment: How would I open the file to be able to use it? To my knowledge using f = open('server.properties', 'w') was opening the file.

Comment: yes that's correct, some line of code in the middle would be closing your file, to make sure just open the file again using `f = open('server.properties', 'w')` before your f.write